# What does ask-password = 1 (action) mean for the monero cli wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cli

I set ask-password = 1 (action). What does action mean? 2 means always ask password for everything you do right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 means do not ask for things like transfer, etc. The password will still be needed to change settings, since this requires writing the keys file, which is encrypted with the password.

1 means ask for things like transfer. The password is checked, and the command only proceeds if the password is correct.

2 means ask for things like transfer, but the spend key is actually encrypted in RAM, so that it can only be read again with the password. This is basically like 1, except the check is not only a "is the password correct", but "if the password is not correct, I don't even have the spend key". This guards against a memory dump of the process exposing the spend key. Monero takes steps to avoid core files or swapping of sensitive data, but this is just another layer of defense.

Comment: where do you find this documentation explaining these values?

Comment: "help set"  spam for stupid length checker, how idiotic

Comment: "help set" only shows: ask-password <0|1|2>  --- it doesn't explain what each of these values do.

Comment: Use a newer version maybe.